What is Recursive partition on /dev/sda
The disk I’m trying to recover the file system from, gives the error invalid partition table - recursive partition on /dev/sda. Is there a way to fix this particular problem? I’m using parted to recover the files.

parted /dev/sda unit MiB print please (in your question, text formatted with the {} button)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

"Recursive partition" would mean that there is an error in the partition table such that a partition refers back to itself, so that the disk would appear to contain a partition, that would contain a partition, that would contain a partition... in an infinite loop.
For a MBR-partitioned disk, I think the extended partition would be the most likely one to suffer from this problem, as neither primary nor logical partitions are expected to contain further partitions, but extended partitions are.
You could fix this by finding out where the actual start and end points of each filesystem on the disk are, and reconstructing the partition table to match those. You can probably do this manually using parted and basic command-line tools, but it is going to be tedious and error-prone work.
If you haven't already tried it, I would recommend using testdisk (available in the package collections of most major Linux distributions) or a similar automated tool that can find the filesystem start/end points and suggest a reconstructed partition table for you.

I'm guessing that the first partition starts from the first sector, so that it contains the primary partition table. Still waiting to see the output from parted though
